# Calling the javascript function from obj c class not working for me

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, webview

This is not working for me to call a javascript function in HTML page from objective C class

Can any one tell me a better way to call a function......

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript:values()"];
```

in the values method i am just placing an alert which displays "Hello world"

and i tried with all possible ways like this

1. [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript:values()"];
2. [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"values()"];

3  NSString *val=[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"values();"]];

pls help me my html doc is somthing like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            alert("Just entered in to script");
            function values()
            {
                alert("In function success");

            }
            </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
       Hello 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question needs to be cleaned up. I would, but it's hard to do editing on mobile safari, so I have flagged instead.

Comment: Can you please tell me about the method that you wish to call. Is it "values()" or something else ?

Comment: Have you tried something else?  Such as an alert instead?

Comment: ya i had tried by placing an alert and document.write("Hello"); even though its not working

Comment: in the values method i am just placing an alert which displays "Hello world"

Answer (score 1):

Please try to call method like this (remove "javascript:") it may help you. Once i had used like this

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"values();"];
```

and inside

```
function values()
{
 //try this
 navigator.notification.alert("In function success");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
[self writeJavascript:@"values();"];
```